# How to avoid objects intersecting and sinking into the base object with geometry nodes?

Tags: objects, geometry, geometry-nodes

I am new to geometry nodes and I made a simple node architecture to achieve the result shown in this [imgur image folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gApb1.jpg). As you can see from the second image, roses tend to intersect with each other and to sink into the ak-47. The nodes architecture I am using is shown in the third image, and it refers to the ak-47 object ('root' in the Point instance is the rose object).

I would like to achieve a better distribution of roses upon the ak-47. Any suggestions or changes to make to the geometry nodes?

Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 2):

With Poisson disc + distance you can prevent the instances from intersecting:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. What version of Blender is this? Nodes seem tobe different with respect to the once I have.

Comment: is it Blender 3.1.0 alpha

Comment: if you tell me your version, i can provide a solution for your version

Comment: I just downloaded the 3.1 alpha version so I was able to use your same nodes. The problem is that I am getting weird distributions over the base object, as you can see from these two pics https://imgur.com/a/L113gFW. Any help?